# Error sending a string to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-first

I'm working on a project with C# and SQL Server. I have a table called `Area` and it has a column called `flag`, it is a `char(1)`.

I create the object with the following code:

```
Area objArea = new Area()
{
    CodArea = txtCod.Text.ToString().ToUpper().Trim(),
    NameArea= txtNombre.Text.ToString().ToUpper().Trim(),
    UserCreate= Session.CurrentSession.User.User1,
    DateCreate= DateTime.Now,
    Flag= "A"
};
```

It worked okay until yesterday but now the program shows this message:

> the field flag should be an string or array with length 1.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

I'm using Entity Framework, I catch the exception with the following code:

```
public void Insert(Area data)
{
        dataBase.Area.Add(data);

        try
        {
            dataBase.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach(var errors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach(var error in errors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0}, Error: {1}",
                                             error.PropertyName,
                                             error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

[image: I'm working in spanish, so the field "FLAG" it's actually "Estado"]
Interesting fact: I have another class called Product and I send the value "A" for flag and it doesnt have any error.

This is the class, is auto-generated

```
public partial class Area
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Area()
    {
        this.Articuloes = new HashSet<Articulo>();
    }

    public int Id_Area { get; set; }
    public string CodArea { get; set; }
    public string NombreArea { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioCreacion { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioModificacion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaModificacion { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Articulo> Articuloes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at what is sent to SQL server using the SQL profiler?

Comment: How do you insert the data? ADO.Net ? Entity Framework?

Comment: Where is the error coming from?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I updated the question

Comment: Did you use EF to create you database or you created it mannually ?

Comment: I created the DB manually

Comment: Any chances we could get a screen shot of the table schema?

Comment: @MaxYoung I updated the description

Comment: Can you try and send `'A'` or `new char[]{ 'A'}` instead of `"A"`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the class have Flag as String not char. I don't create the entities, they were created with the EF.

Comment: Try nchar instead of char

Comment: can you place show the `Area` class that EF creates.

Comment: @PeterSmith done!

Comment: Looks like the flag is set (or emptied) somewhere else too. You could temporarily turn it into a property with backing field (`private string _estado`) and set a break point on the setter.